# Latex cannot find my Beamer sty file

Tags: beamer, kpathsea

On Linux, I've downloaded the "[diepen](https://github.com/gdiepen/beamerthemediepen)" Beamer theme to my `~/texmf` folder. I've run `texhash ~/texmf`, which happily creates an `ls-R` file containing this:

```
% ls-R -- filename database for kpathsea; do not change this line.
./:
.:
beamerthemediepen-master
ls-R

[some lines omitted]

./beamerthemediepen-master/themes/theme:
beamerthemediepen.sty
```

But if I then run `kpsewhich beamerthemediepen.sty`, it prints nothing. And, indeed, trying to use `\usetheme{diepen}` in my Beamer file results in this error message:

```
 File `beamerthemediepen.sty' not found.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably need to be in tds structure, have you tried to create tex/latex/diepen, place drhe sty in there and run texhash again.

Comment: @dailef: Thank you, that worked. If you change your comment to an answer, I will acknowledge it as the answer to my question.

Comment: You don't need to run `texhash`. Unless you've changed the global configuration, no database is needed or used for `~/texmf` @daleif.

Comment: @cfr it should not hurt

Comment: @daleif It won't hurt, but it isn't needed.